# SimpleCursorAdapter is undefined?

Tags: java, android

Below is the sample of code giving me grief. The simpleCursorAdapter works if I put it outside of the textchangedlistener but not in I keep getting the message

> The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(new TextWatcher(){}, int, Cursor, String, int, null) is undefined

```
txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //onTextChanged
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //beforeTextChanged

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //afterTextChanged
                typedText = s.toString();

                Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                        DB_TABLE +" where field LIKE '%" + typedText + "%'" , null);
                String displayFields = "field";
                int displayViews = R.id.bmark_visits;
                setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                R.layout.testlist, cur, 
                                displayFields, displayViews, null
                ));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor should be your activity. However, inside of your anonymous `TextWatcher` inner class, `this` is the instance of the anonymous TextWatcher inner class. Use `MyActivity.this` instead, where `MyActivity` is the name of your activity.

Comment: so i should set the this in the simplecursoradapter to read the class.this? Sorry I'm slightly confused how to reference the activity. Do i need to use the package name too?

Comment: @Max: "so i should set the this in the simplecursoradapter to read the class.this?" -- yes, as I wrote above. "Do i need to use the package name too?" -- probably not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly I must still be missing something at this end. The class is called Test so i have changed this to read Test.this, but still appears the undefined constructor message

Comment: @Max: Is `Test` an `Activity`?

Comment: Again thank you for your help. It's late here and I think im just confused. I'll try fresh again in the morning. Test is just the name of the class that all of this is running in. The package it is all running in is com.test.llm  I was thinking at first i needed to set MyActivity to com.test.llm.Test.this

Answer (score 0):

You should call activity's manage cursor method. Otherwise, they will leak out.

```
activity.startManagingCursor( cursor );
```

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Where should this be placed?

Comment: As soon as you get a cursor inside an activity.